# Passing parameters to raw SQL queries inside ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I want to execute a raw SQL query using rails active record, but my query takes a parameter, I can't find a proper way to safely pass that parameter into the query string. The query is as follows

```
def self.get_branches_by_workspace_name(workspace_name)
  branches = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
    select
      address,
      phone,
      email,
      services
    from branches as b, workspaces as w
    where b.workspace_id = w.id and w.name= :workspace_name", workspace_name).to_a
  return branches
end
```

I would like to pass a parameter named "workspace_name". Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your model add this method

```
  def self.execute_sql(*sql_array)     
   connection.execute(sanitize_sql_array(sql_array))
  end
```

This will let you sanitize and execute arbitrary SQL in an AR model

Then run something like this to execute the SQL, returning an array of hashes, one per row returned by your query

```
ModelName.execute_sql("select address,phone,email,services from branches as b, workspaces as w 
    where b.workspace_id = w.id and w.name= ?", workspace_name)

# => [{"address"=>"...","phone"=>"...","email"=>"...","services"=>"..."}, ...]
```

Comment: Why do you need `send`? The `sanitize_sql_array` method is protected.

Answer (score 12):

Outside your model:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
  ApplicationRecord.sanitize_sql([query, { param_1: param_1, param_2: param_2 }])
)
```

Comment: Should "ApplicationRecord.sanitize_sql" be changed to "ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize_sql"?

Comment: best, most straightforward answer IMO

Answer (score 5):

In your model you can do this

```
  sql_command = <<-SQL
    SELECT address, phone, email, services
    FROM branches as b, workspaces as w
    WHERE b.workspace_id = w.id and w.name = :workspace_name
  SQL

  connection.execute(
    sanitize_sql_for_assignment([sql_command, workspace_name: "whatever"])
  )
```